# Boot Windows from USB, but run off of HD?

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I've got what looks to be a BIOS issue with an older Toshiba: it works great with smaller disks, but when I put in a 1TB mSATA, the *BIOS* doesn't see it, and, thus, can't boot to it.  BUT... both Windows and Linux, when booted from USB, see the disk fine.  Which seems to very much indicate that it's a BIOS-level problem.  Note that bootloaders (e.g., GRUB) likewise can't see the disk, probably because they are relying on the same primitives the BIOS is, and have not loaded up drivers like the OSes have.  If this were Linux, it would be easy to boot the kernel off of USB and then switch control to the HD as part of the boot sequence.  But I have no idea how do that for Windows, or if it's even possible.  I should also mention that I've also checked BIOS updates, and it's at the latest rev.  Suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into a bios firmware update?

Comment: Thanks, @LPChip -- forgot to mention that.  I'm at the latest firmware update, from two years ago.  Updated the original post to mention that.

Comment: How old is this system?  Is this a laptop or desktop?  Unless it's more than about 8 years old it should have some flavor of UEFI and not have a problem--do you have CSM enabled?

Comment: It's about eight years old, but does have UEFI, UEFI (legacy) and CSM -- I've tried 'em all, with exactly the same result.  And, it's a laptop, else I'd be puttin' me a different controller in there, and sure the heck not using mSATA. ;-)

Comment: I don't have a solution for you and you appear to be very smart.. however.. ***you have NO BIOS.. there is ONLY UEFI.***  Perhaps understanding [how UEFI REALLY works](https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) might help (perhaps not).  I would try to set to UEFI boot and use a windows 10 installer made with the media creation tool.  Format the disk GPT.. and install.  As stupid as it sounds, you might be surprised to see your disk show up on the next boot (or not and curse my name). Its worth a shot.

Comment: Well, I actually do understand how UEFI works, though I think it's fair to use the word "BIOS" as a generic stand-in for whatever firmware is being the smarts for your computer.  As for your idea, alas, no dice: one of the first things I did was install Ubuntu (the disk was already GPT), in the hopes that it would update the EFI boot partition such that I could choose which OS to boot, and then I'd alter stuff to make Windows the default.  Alas... no dice.  Ubuntu installed fine, but upon reboot, zilch.